# How to download an interpreter package for pycharm?

Tags: python, download, pycharm, package, interpreter

I need to use Pycharm 2.7 interpreter.

When searching the internet many sites are giving detailed explanations of how to get Pycharm to run/activate the Pycharm interpreter packages, WHEN they are already on your computer.

I want to download the package for Pycharms 2.7 interpreter package, can someone please direct me to where I can download it onto my pc?

Comment: just download it from python.org. [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/) is a link to the 2.7 page, just pick the package you need. assuming you are on a 64bit windows machine, you will need `Windows x86-64 MSI installer`

Comment: Or use conda (e.g. miniconda or anaconda). It is well integrated with PyCharm, and it handles virtual environment and different interpreters (and other scientific languages). I recommend conda if you use also more modern python interpreters (so not just 2.7, but many different versions)